# Batch window opens and shuts immediately?

Tags: batch-file, window

I have this code in my batch file, but when I open it, it closes itself immediately. What do I do? It should work without adding any pauses.

```
@echo off
color f0
:start1
cls
set /a wait=50000
set /a limit=2147483646
set /a current=0
echo WAITING ROOM SIMULATOR 2014
echo Current Number:%current%
echo Your number is 2,147,483,647
goto loop1
:loop1
set /a wait=%wait%-50000
set /a current=%current%+1
if current=limit goto pause1
goto start2
:loop2
set /a wait=%wait%+1
if %wait%=50000 goto loop1
:start2
cls
echo WAITING ROOM SIMULATOR 2014
echo Current Number:%current%
echo Your number is 2,147,483,647
goto loop2
:pause1
goto pause2
:pause2
goto pause1
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a problem with syntax, specifically `if current=limit goto pause1` and `if %wait%=50000 goto loop1` see the fixed file below:

```
@echo off
color f0
:start1
cls
set /a wait=50000
set /a limit=2147483646
set /a current=0
echo WAITING ROOM SIMULATOR 2014
echo Current Number:%current%
echo Your number is 2,147,483,647
goto loop1
:loop1
set /a wait=%wait%-50000
set /a current=%current%+1
if %current%==%limit% goto pause1
goto start2
:loop2
set /a wait=%wait%+1
if %wait%==50000 goto loop1
:start2
cls
echo WAITING ROOM SIMULATOR 2014
echo Current Number:%current%
echo Your number is 2,147,483,647
goto loop2
:pause1
goto pause2
:pause2
goto pause1
```

Comment: That fixed the problem, thanks. It was just an arbitrary project to practice making timers in batch, along with using the set command.